# Cronjob in react JS

Tags: reactjs, cron

There is no solution for React to support cron jobs. Could you please share your solutions/alternatives for scheduling events in React?

One solution might be to find a time difference between now and scheduled time and setTimeout for that difference.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` would be the way to accomplish this in React. For instance, you could use `setInterval()` to call a function that checks if the current time is equal to a cron job's scheduled time every second or so.

However, this sounds like a job better suited for a process running on a server that can then update react when it needs to.